# Widget with text input on datadog dashboard

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard

I need to create a time series widget (or another type if time series is not possible) that takes a text input (a value I get from another existing widget) and uses it as a variable for the graph.
An example would be "get me all error logs for X" where X is the variable. I've been trying the existing widgets and can't find one that does it.
Thanks!